# If I have created a ViewController with a picker and second one with details based on the picker selection can I duplicate it?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, plist, duplication

I have an 2 ViewControllers that I have created to work together in a project. You press a Button on a Page and the First ViewController opens. On the first ViewController you select an Error Code thru a PickerView based on a supplied Plist then you press the Select Button and the second ViewController opens and Populates from the Plist based on what was selected in the first ViewController..

Is it possible to Duplicate the UIViewers to use with a seperate Plist of the same structure but different information?

I want to use the same ViewControllers and code else where in the project with different data!

Is this possible and if so how would I go about it?

Do I duplicate the ViewControllers and then the ViewController.h and ViewController.m files associated with them and rename everything then reference the other PLIST as needed?

I want to use it with a few times oin my current project!

Is this the correct way to do it or can someone tell me an better way to do what I am wanting to do?

==================================================================================

Edited for possible answer explanations in more details or better answer!

Like I said I am new to XCODE and OOP and I am reading and trying things but this does seem to stump me.

I also have multiple PDF files I would like to access from a viewcontroller with buttons that select each PDF to open with as simple code as possible. I can do this with a button opening a webview for each PDF ( each has its own webview "subclass viewcontroller") but can I do it with one view controller??

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You can either re-use them in code as separate instances (both use ViewController.h and ViewController.m)

```
ViewController* myvc1 = [[ViewController alloc] init];
ViewController* myvc2 = [[ViewController alloc] init];
```

or reuse them via loading their xib / storyboard files:

```
UIStoryboard sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
ViewController* myc1 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
ViewController* myc2 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more as to how this will work. I am fairly new to XCode and OOP but I am reading and trying things to see how they do work. I do appreciate your response also and any other assistance you may provide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and you can re-use the same controller in 'n' times with different instances with differentiation on code. But as per regular scenario we create multiple controllers to better identify the differentiation of functionality.